# KSQLDB asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I don't see any article/blog written around `KSQL DB` for `asp.net core` and there are less/no documentation available. It would be appreciated if you could help me with the code/article/blog on `kSQLDB` with `asp.net core`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ksqlDB.RestApi.Client package](https://github.com/tomasfabian/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client-DotNet) in .NET / C#.

```
Install-Package ksqlDB.RestApi.Client
```

There is an [AspNet Blazor sample](https://github.com/tomasfabian/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client-DotNet/tree/main/Samples/Blazor.Sample) in tomasfabian\ksqlDB.RestApi.Client-DotNet GitHub repository. It demonstrates how to use ksqldb streams, tables and [monitor push notifications from SQL Server](https://github.com/tomasfabian/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client-DotNet/blob/main/SqlServer.Connector/Wiki.md) with a connector. You can react to these topics (streams/tables) with a Kafka consumer or ksqldb client.

Clone the repository:

```
https://github.com/tomasfabian/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client-DotNet.git;
```

Open InsideOut.sln in Visual Studio 2019 and set docker-compose as startup project.

This [console app](https://github.com/tomasfabian/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client-DotNet/tree/main/Samples/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client.Sample) contains LINQ to ksqldb query examples. There are also some [LinqPad samples available](https://github.com/tomasfabian/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client-DotNet/tree/main/Samples/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client.LinqPad).

You should also check the [Readme](https://github.com/tomasfabian/ksqlDB.RestApi.Client-DotNet#readme).

I think that this could be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score -2):

ksqlDB is written in **Java**, thus cannot be "hosted" by ASP.NET infrastructure. Similarly, to my knowledge, there is no Kafka Streams equivalent library for .NET.

[ksqlDB offers a REST API](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/api/) if you needed to interact with it from other languages